# php.ini ~E_WARNING crash phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Setting the following in php.ini make phpmyadmin stop working

**error_reporting = E_ALL ~E_WARNING**

i get the following while acessing localhost/phpmyadmin

**phpMyAdmin - Error**

The mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

Please help

Comment: Did you check your PHP config, you know like it said?

Comment: yes of course and it run fine without the ~E-WARNING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_WARNING
```